# Make graphic button to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, jcomponent

I have a nice problem, because I have 3 classes:

1. WindowFrame - its a class extends JFrame, which will show one of panels inside;
2. WindowPanel - it is a class extends JPanel. I have layout BoxLayout there. I want switch between other panels in WindowFrame;
3. GButton - its a class something like normal button, but with my texture on bg and I want adding them easy to WindowPanel by add():

---

```
public class GButton extends JComponent implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener{

    int x, y , w, h; //the coordinates of button
    Graphics2D g2d;

    public GButton(int x, int y){
        this.x = x; this.y = y;
        this.w = 200; this.h = 100;
        ... //add listeners, loading some information etc
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        ...//loading and draw on g2d
        g2d.drawString("asidoaisjdiajsoidj",x,y);
    }

    //code with using events of mouse and so on
}
```

And when I add button, the texture of button is 50px below y! Next buttons has grown this difference from y. Why? I know that because I check it with help MouseMove event. It isn't a bad size of images or something like that. Why it isn't working, and it paint things in other places? Is simpler way to get same effect? Please answer :)

Comment: You don't have `public int getX()` and `getY()` methods do you? If so, you could unknowingly override the JComponent's method with disastrous results.

Answer (score 1):

You codes a little thin on the ground, however.

- Don't maintain a reference to the `Graphics` context.  1.  It is reused; 2. It may change between paint cycles.  You are required to paint into the graphics context passed to your component
- You MUST call `super.paintComponent`, this is incredibly important.

I can't be 100% sure, but you appear that be under the impression that you are required to paint to the x/y position that the button appears on the screen, this is incorrect.  The `Graphics` context has already being translated so that position 0x0 is the top/left corner of your object.

I'd suggest you need to spend some time reading through

- [Performing custom painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Answer (score 0):

Never keep a global reference to `Graphics` (and as well 2D).

If you do need, call `g2d.dispose()` at the end of each drawing, obtaining a new graphical context the next time you want to use it.

Comment: @iccthedral: I'm betting that you do. :)

Comment: @MouseEvent You only need to call `dispose` if you create the graphics context (ie calling `Graphics#create`), otherwise you should NEVER call dispose - if you create it, you dispose it